# Bone/armature mirror option isn't working

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, mirror

I'm practicing rigging a model and tried to enable the axis mirror in the options menu on the left side of the screen in the tab but it's not working. I recently updated to the latest version of blender and I haven't used this option before.

Does anyone know what could be stopping the axis mirror from working? Also using screenshot to help explain would be a huge help since I'm a visual learner :)

Also due to copyright reasons I can't upload the model, sorry.

Comment: You could upload the armature only

Answer (score 2):

I found an alternate solution to mirror bones :)

1. Select the bones you want to duplicate.
2. Duplicate the bones(shift D).
3. Press S for scale.
4. Press X for axis.
5. Type -1 to flip it.
6. Press Enter and violá! Mirrored armature/bones :)

Answer (score 2):

X-Axis mirror needs mirror'd assets to work.  The easiest way is to Mirror-extrude the bones with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> in armature edit mode.  This only needs to happen once, from then on it will track extrusions, duplications, and transformations across the x-axis, as long as the bones keep with similar L/R naming schemes.

Beyond that, we cannot diagnose the particular issue you have until we have more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Rename the bones with proper names as R_ or L_ as prefix then symmetry in armature works